# How to configure Stunnel to work with Internet explorer

Tags: stunnel

My application works in the following way:
The browsers are configured with a local proxy which is an instance of Stunnel running in Client mode that connects to a remote server to another instance of Stunnel running in Server mode that directs the traffic through a real proxy.

I understand there's a bug in IE that requires a workaround in Stunnel - adding `TIMEOUTclose = 0` in the configuration.

My question is where should I put this directive ? In the Stunnel Client configuration or in Stunnel Server configuration ?

Answer (score 0):

So your setup looks something like this:

```
IE <--plaintext--> (stunnel client) <--TLS--> (stunnel server) <--plaintext--> proxy
```

The [bug you're referring to](http://www.stunnel.org/faq.html) applies to IE's TLS/SSL implementation, but in your setup IE isn't communicating with TLS. Therefore you don't need it.

Comment: the setup also allows for IE to perform HTTPS requests through Stunnel. In such a case IE will use TLS, won't it ?